# How can I apply a Postfix Completion to an expression separated by spaces in PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, autocomplete, code-snippets, live-templates

I'm new in PyCharm IDE and I'm now personalizing my code snippets (`Live Templates` | `Postix Completion`) but don't know the syntax and limits of which.

I've seen there is a `Postfix Completion` whose expression adopts the following syntax: `number1, number2.par` and it transforms it into `(number1, number2)`. I rather how could that be done and which syntax does it use in order to achieve that.

I've been searching information in the [JetBrain's oficial page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2023.3/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html) but didn't help much. Is it even possible to create a Porfix Completion whit that estructure?

Same question in spanish in [this link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/616082/sintaxis-para-postfix-completion-en-el-ide-pycharm)

In a nutshell, how can I create a `Postfix Completion` with the following structure in `PyCharm IDE`:

Before:

```
1, 2.par
```

After:

```
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This particular completion have been added by default:
([screenshot of settings window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5fqg.png)).
You can also create custom completions following [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html#custom-postfix-templates).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).